# Redmine high availability instances

Tags: redmine, swarm, pacemaker

Can anyone provide me with an alternative along with the steps to install Redmine HA instances?

I tried to solve it with Docker swarm, but it seems very sophisticated.

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. Also, not sure what you mean by "alternative steps" - you haven't shown anything regarding the actual steps you're taking. (plus, once you rework this question to contain more details, it would fit much better on ServerFault).

Comment: "alternative steps" - means Kubernetes or something. Is it possible to install Redmine in Docker swarm without discovery service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Redmine application itself is (almost, see below) stateless since all state is kept in the underlying database. You can easily run several instances of Redmine on different servers/VMs, all pointing to a single database (cluster) by specifying the database in `database.yml`. The only remaining part would be the file attachments stored in `files/` within Redmine. You would have to put this on a network share.

Any loadbalancing capable reverse proxy (e.g. HAProxy) can then be used to distribute requests across your Redmine instances or to implement a failover in case one of them goes down.

To make your database highly available, you'd have to look into the replication capabilities of your chosen DBMS. For instance, PostgreSQL has a [section about HA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/high-availability.html) in its docs.

It's not black magic but it requires continuous work to make Redmine run fast and reliable at large scale. My company [Planio Redmine Hosting](https://plan.io/redmine-hosting/) does this day in and day out.

Comment: Jan, Bingo! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If you feel that my reply has answered your question, please mark it as such by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Thanks!